# changing onclick methods to tap for ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, mobile

***EG.***

```
<video class="vid" id='video'  height="300" width="500" onclick="vidplay()">


var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
video.play();
},false);
```

This works fine allowing the HTML5 video to be played on desktop. But it however; does not work within ipad. I'm assuming it's the `onclick` method; and I'm assuming I need to convert this to `tap`... but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `element.addEventListener` take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

and you have, "touchstart", "touchend", "touchmove"

So let's say

`function doSomething(){
alert("works");
}`

`element.addEventListener("touchstart", doSomething, false);`

Comment: Thanks but is it still a good practice to follow mozilla developer solutions when working with; specific to iPad / Safari / iOs?

Comment: it's just the first thing that popped up on google when i searched event listeners. I developed many JS apps for mobile (iPhone, hence iOS), and i relied heavely on `touchstart` `touchend` and i can assure you they work perfectly.